# Embed XML into SOAP / PHP encodes lower-than and great-than sign

Tags: php, soap

We have an WSDL that contains the following and make a call using the standard SOAP Client of PHP:

```
<element name="doSomething">
    <complexType>
        <sequence>
            <element name="Payload" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
            <element name="Username" type="string"/>
            <element name="service" type="string"/>
            <element name="Password" type="string"/>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
</element>
```

The Payload is essentially XML data, which looks for example like this

```
<code>1</code>
```

Now the request of the SOAP client, dumped via `echo $client->__getLastRequest();`
 looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="pa/WebshopService"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:doSomething><ns1:Payload>&lt;code&gt;
1
&lt;/code&gt;
</ns1:pcRequest><ns1:Username>bar</ns1:Username><ns1:service>bar</ns1:service><ns1:Password>bar</ns1:Password></ns1:doSomething></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

which, I believe makes sense, as the `<` and `>` should be encoded.

The counterpart seems to expect something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="pa/WebshopService"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:doSomething><ns1:Payload><code>
1
</code>
</ns1:pcRequest><ns1:Username>bar</ns1:Username><ns1:service>bar</ns1:service><ns1:Password>bar</ns1:Password></ns1:doSomething></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

- How can I send such using the PHP SoapClient?
- Is the WSDL even valid in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the complex type `doSomething` says, that the property `Payload` is of type string. Consequently the encoded string of the xml content should be right. If the provider side expects the content not encoded, the property `Payload` would be another complex type. So in this case the wsdl is not valid, if it 's true, that the provider side really wants an element and not an encoded string.

Anyway, there 's a solution you can handle this with PHP. Just handle `Payload` not as a string. Instead make a complex type out of it.

```
class DoSomething()
{
    protected $Payload;

    protected $Username;

    protected $Service;

    protected $Password;

    public function getPayload() : ?\SoapVar        {
        return $this->Payload;
    }

    public function setPayload(\SoapVar $payload) : DoSomething
    {
        $this->Payload = $payload;
        return $this;
    }

    ...

    public function encode() : \SoapVar
    {
        return new \SoapVar(
            $this,
            SOAP_ENC_OBJECT,
            null,
            null,
            'doSomething',
            'http://www.example.com/namespace'
        );
    }
}
```

Above you see the complex type `doSomething` as a PHP class. You also see an examplary getter and setter method. The get method returns null or a \SoapVar instance. The setter method takes a \SoapVar instance.

For your purpose you 'll need another PHP class for the `Payload` property, which contains the `code` property.

```
class Payload
{
    protected $Code;

    public function getCode() : ?\SoapVar
    {
        return $this->Code;
    }

    public function setCode(\SoapVar $code) : Payload
    {
        $this->Code = $code;
        return $this;
    }

    public function encode() : \SoapVar
    {
        return new \SoapVar
        {
            $this,
            SOAP_ENC_OBJECT,
            null,
            null,
            'Payload',
            'http://www.example.com/namespace'
        }
    }
}
```

Now just put all together ...

```
$code = new \SoapVar(1, XSD_INT, null, null, 'code');

$payload = (new Payload())
    ->setCode($code)
    ->encode();

$doSomething = (new DoSomething())
    ->setPayload($payload)
    ->setUsername(...)
    ->setService(...)
    ->setPassword(...)
    ->encode();

$result = $client->doSomething($doSomething);
```

Now your request should look like ...

```
<ns1:doSomething>
    <ns1:Payload>
        <code>1</code>
    </ns1:Payload>
    <ns1:Username>...</ns1:Username>
    <ns1:Service>...</ns1:Service>
    <ns1:Password>...</ns1:Password>
</ns1:doSomething>
```

Hope that helped you.

Comment: So just let out the namspace parameter, when initiating the \SoapVar class for the code property. I 've edited my answer that way.

Comment: How "hacky" would you call that solution?

Comment: I won 't call it "hacky" at all. On your side (consumer / php side) this solution is clean because it 's all native PHP and no workaround or polyfill. It's okay to iron out the provider's problems with a web service that is not declared clean. Consider, that the native PHP soap client got a classmap option, where you can list all webservice complex types. It 's kinda natural working with classes and in context the soap classes php provides on its own when realising a soap client.